# Would like to split a string using a regex pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that I would like to split into

```
var finalQuote = "2012-0001-1";
var quoteNum = "2012-0001";
var revision = "1"
```

I used something like this

```
var quoteNum = quoteNum.subString(0,9);
var revision = quoteNum.subString(quoteNum.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
```

But can't it be done using regex more efficiently? I come across patterns like this that need to be split into two.

```
 var finalQuote = "2012-0001-1";
 string pat = @"(\d|[A-Z]){4}-\d{4}";
 Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 Match m = r.Match(text);
 var quoteNum = m.Value;
```

So far I have reached here. But I feel I am not using the correct method. Please guide me.

**EDIT**: I wanna edit by the pattern. Splitting with dashes is not an option as the first part of the split contains a dash. ie, `"2012-0001"`

Comment: I'm not a C# guy, but does it have a `split` functionality like Javascript? Then you could just `finalQuote.split("-")[1]` and get your `0001` value.

Comment: Regex is hardly known for its efficiency.

Comment: If you have a fixed number of characters, you better use your substring method.

Comment: @Grant- Agreed. Regex can actually decrease code readability in some scenarios since not everyone is familiar with regex.  If there is a simple 2 liner to do it I would avoid the regex, you can always add it in later if the string becomes more complex.

Comment: guys, i agree, i have all sort of split at this project with patterns. if i get a regex split to work then i could just do a pattern split that gives me a string[] ideally. hope it makes sense.

Comment: @downvoter: is it a crime to try and learn? care to explain the minus vote?

Comment: If i need to use a RegEx i'm going to use [RegEx Hero](http://regexhero.net) cause it uses the C# RegEx engine, provides intelli sense and immediate highlighting of the elements found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with others that using substring is a better solution than regex for this.
But if you're insisting on using regex you can use something like:

```
^(\d{4}-\d{4})-(\d)$
```

Untested since I don't have a C# environment installed:

```
var finalQuote = "2012-0001-1";
string pat = @"^(\d{4}-\d{4})-(\d)$";
Regex r = new Regex(pat);
Match m = r.Match(finalQuote);
var quoteNum = m.Groups[1].Value;
var revision = m.Groups[2].Value;
```

Alternatively, if you want a `string[]` you could try (again, untested):

```
string[] data = Regex.Split("2012-0001-1",@"-(?=\d$)");
```

`data[0]` would be `quoteNum` and `data[1]` would be `revision`.

**Update:**

Explanation of the `Regex.Split`:

From the `Regex.Split` documentation: *The Regex.Split methods are similar to the String.Split method, except that Regex.Split splits the string at a delimiter determined by a regular expression instead of a set of characters.*

The regex `-(?=\d$)` matches a single `-` given it is followed by `a digit followed by the end of the string` so it would only match the last dash in the string. The last digit is not consumed because we use a [zero-width lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=)`

Comment: +1. that one-liner is brilliant. it works for me. can you explain that a bit? i did not understand much.

Answer (score 4):

I would simply go with:

```
var quoteNum = finalQuote.Substring(0,9);
var revision = finalQuote.Substring(10);
```

`quoteNum` would consist of the first 9 characters, and `revision` of the 10th and everything that may follow the 10th, e.g. if the revision is 10 or higher it would still work.

Using complicated regexes or extension methods is very quickly overkill; sometimes the simple methods are efficient enough by itself.

Answer (score 1):

sIt would be easier to maintain in the future if you something that the new comer would understand.

you could use:

```
var finalQuote = "2012-0001-1";
string[] parts = finalQuote.Split("-");
var quoteNum = parts[0] + "-" + parts[1] ;
var revision = parts[3];
```

However if you insists you need a regEx then

```
(\d{4}-\d{4})-(\d)
```

There are two groups in this expression, group 1 capture the first part and the group 2 capture the second part.

```
var finalQuote = "2012-0001-1";
string pat = @"(\d{4}-\d{4})-(\d)";
Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match m = r.Match(finalQuote);
var quoteNum = m.Groups[1].Value;
var revision = m.Groups[2].Value;
```

Comment: thanks, i understand. This is what is looked for. you may wanna change the code like this, right? `var quoteNum = m.Groups[1].Value;
var revision = m.Groups[2].Value;` as `Groups[0].value` returns the passed string itself. I was really hoping to learn and your code worked brilliantly for me. thanks once more